# How to calculate conditional average in data frame in R?

Tags: r, conditional-statements, average

Suppose we have a data set, a snippet looks like:

```
count  party  gender
0      Rep    F
2      Rep    M
3      Rep    F
```

I'm trying to calculate the average value of the `count` column if `party = Rep` and `gender = F`. I.e. it should be 1.5 here. How can this be written in R code?

Answer (score 3):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% filter(party == 'Rep' & gender == 'F') %>% summarise(avg = mean(count))
# A tibble: 1 x 1
    avg
  <dbl>
1   1.5
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use base R:

```
mean(df[(df$party == 'Rep' & df$gender == 'F'),]$count)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`:

```
setDT(dt)
dt[, mean(count), .(party, gender)]
```

Output:

```
   party gender  V1
1:   Rep      F 1.5
2:   Rep      M 2.0
```

This will calculate the `mean` of `count` for all `party`-`gender` pairs, in the case that you want to include all combinations (not just only `Rep`/`F`).

Data:

```
dt = read.table(text = 'count  party  gender
0      Rep    F
2      Rep    M
3      Rep    F
', header = T)
```